# Curl command to get time taken

Tags: linux, http, curl

I'm running a curl command:

```
curl -s -w "\n\n%{time_connect} + %{time_starttransfer} = %{time_total}\n\n" GET http://www.google.com
```

and the response that I'm getting is:

```
0.000 + 0.000 = 0.000

<HTML><HEAD><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
<TITLE>302 Moved</TITLE></HEAD><BODY>
<H1>302 Moved</H1>
The document has moved
<A HREF="http://www.google.co.in/?gfe_rd=cr&amp;dcr=0&amp;ei=zWUAWsbbDabU-APf85KoBQ">here</A>.
</BODY></HTML>


0.217 + 0.416 = 0.417
```

So one thing that I'm not understanding is that why two instances of the time taken and what are they representing ??

```
0.000 + 0.000 = 0.000

0.217 + 0.416 = 0.417
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You don't need `GET` in `curl` command and it try `GET` and fails and that result is given in with first output with zeros.

Remove the `GET` from the `curl` command and try.

```
curl -w "\n\n%{time_connect} + %{time_starttransfer} = %{time_total}\n" www.google.com
```

Comment: But why the different set of time ? what do they represent ?

Comment: I think i have answered it now. @gautam